# Python recordlinkage toolkit - Mappings not known

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using http://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
How do I provide mappings between the datasets when there are some columns in Dataset 1 which do not consistently map to the same column in Dataset 2. 
Basically, the mapping is not known and what I would like to specify is - Dataset1.Column1 could be mapped to either Dataset2.Column1 or Dataset2.Column2 or Dataset2.Column3
How would I specify the compare attributes for the same?

```
compare_cl = rl.Compare(pairs, dfA, dfB)
compare_cl.string(?, ?);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `recordlinkage` does not enforce any kind of mapping when comparing records, so you can compare any two columns from the two dataframes, regardless of whether those columns have been compared previously.

In your case, you could do the following:

```
compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare(pairs, dfA, dfB)
compare_cl.string('dfA-column-1', 'dfB-column-1')
compare_cl.string('dfA-column-1', 'dfB-column-2')
compare_cl.string('dfA-column-1', 'dfB-column-3')
```

`recordlinkage` can only make comparisons between individual columns. So, if the values that you want to compare occur across multiple columns, this will need to addressed in either the preprocessing stage or the classification stage.

If at all possible, try to address this problem with data pre-processing. I don't know the specifics of your problem, but it sounds like your data may be structured in a way that would make record linkage messy if not addressed early in the workflow. I highly recommend checking out [Hadley Wickham's Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) for a primer on data cleaning.

If the data you want to compare can be put into a single column, do that. If records in `dfA` correspond to `dfB-column-1`, or to `dfB-column-2`, or to `dfB-column-3`, but not to all three, you should consider whether you could "reshape" `dfB` to solve your problem e.g. by converting you data to ["long format"](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/) and then using a blocking criteria (i.e. with `recordlinkage.BlockIndex`) to ignore meaningless comparisons.

If (for whatever reason) you are unable to work this out during preprocessing, you could apply conditions when classifying candidate links as matches/non-matches.